# Generic Repository Method throws conversion error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following repository method that applies a filter and then orders the collection:

```
  public IQueryable<TE> SelectAll(Expression<Func<TE, bool>> predicate, 
            Expression<Func<TE, object>> sortExpression, bool orderDescending = false)
        {
            var list = _ctx.CreateQuery<TE>("[" + typeof(TE).Name + "]")
                .AsExpandable().Where(predicate);

            return orderDescending 
                ? list.OrderByDescending(sortExpression) 
                : list.OrderBy(sortExpression);
        }
```

The where predicate works fine, but when if the OrderBy is applied we get the following error:

**Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.**

Edit: This is the calling code:

```
 var documentos = SelectAll(d => serviciosId.Contains(d.ServicioId) && d.TipoSociedadId == tipoSociedadId, d => d.Grupo);
```

Comment: what type is `d.Grupo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public IQueryable<TE> SelectAll<TE, TKey>(Expression<Func<TE, bool>> predicate, 
            Expression<Func<TE, TKey>> sortExpression, bool orderDescending = false)
{
    var list = _ctx.CreateQuery<TE>("[" + typeof(TE).Name + "]")
                   .AsExpandable().Where(predicate);

    return orderDescending 
        ? list.OrderByDescending(sortExpression) 
        : list.OrderBy(sortExpression);
}
```

The problem is that the second parameter of the `Func` in the `OrderBy` clause is `object` in your code, and you are passing it an `int`, then it tries to cast that `int` to `object`. In the code I pasted above, you have an extra generic parameter that allows you to pass in any type for the ordering function, so, that should work.

Comment: @amhed: Sorry, that was a typo, you need to add the generic parameter to the method definition, something like `SellectAll<TE, TKey>` and remove the `TKey` from the `IQueryable`. I edited my post.